# How do I query node sort by randomize?

Tags: 8

I want to get all articles content type, but I want to get it randomize, how can I do that? Refer to my code below:

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'articles')->sort('RAND()')->execute();
```

I'm using drupal 8

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with an entity query directly, but you can alter entity queries after they are converted into select queries.

Add a tag to your entity query and then you can alter it there.

```
  $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->addTag('sort_by_random')
    ->execute();
```

Then add a query alter function to your custom module using the tag you added.  Drupal's select query even has a [built in function to make a query sort on "RAND()"](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/function/Select%3A%3AorderRandom/8.2.x):

```
function mymodule_query_sort_by_random_alter(\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->orderRandom();
}
```

If you're going to have to tag an entity query to alter it, and it's not essential that you use an entity query, you might want to just replace it with a select query.

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'n')
  ->fields('n', ['nid'])
  ->condition('type', 'article')
  ->range(0, 10)
  ->orderRandom();

$results = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

if (!empty($results)) {
  $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($results);
}
```

Comment: Can I add query alter function in ```mytheme.theme``` file?

Comment: @oknate, any way to add a seed variable to the mysql `rand(seed)` function? - for consistent randomized pagination.